# Why mongo aggregate remove all records?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.getCollection('alert').aggregate([{
        "$match":{
            "_id":{
                "$in":[]
             }
         }
    },
    {
        "$addFields":{
            "state":"RESOLVED",
            "log":{
                "$concatArrays":["$log",[{ "message": "HOT alert"}]
            }
         },
    {
        "$out":"alert"
    }
])
```

My mongodb version is 4.0.4
I am using above query to  update alerts match with  first pipeline. 
I don't know why after I run this query, the records not match with conditions were deleted.
If match, the records is updated and don't be remove, just records not match with condition be removed.

Please check and help me. How I can keep all record not match with condition but still update match records

Comment: Maybe check the other part of your code as well. This part seems ok

Comment: `$out` will replace your existing collection with the newly created collection i.e. the output from the `$out` aggregation.

Comment: @Ashh yes, how I can merge exists colelction with newly created collection, I find out on mongo document, they had `$merge` but it support only 4.2 or later. I using 4.0.4

Comment: You can remove your first `$match` and add the `$cond` with `$addFIelds` stage. But first let me know your condition

Comment: @Ashh It very simple, just push an object to array `log` and set `state` to `RESOLVED` for alerts has id in array `{ $in: [ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...)]}`.

Comment: sample:
I have 10 alerts with id is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
I want to update alerts: 1,3,5. Push an object to log array and set state to resolved for 1,3,5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$cond` with `$addFields` stage

```
db.getCollection("alert").aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "state": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$_id", [YOUR_IDS]] }, "RESOLVED", "$state"]
      },
      "log": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$in": ["$_id", [YOUR_IDS]] },
          { "$concatArrays": ["$log", [{ "message": "HOT alert" }]] },
          "$log"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$out": "alert" }
])
```

Comment: But I have a question about your query. If I remove `$match` condition on first object in pipeline array, this query will run through all records and state will be updated if meet `$cond`

If I don't remove `$match`, It will run only on matched records, right?

Comment: @VũAnhDũng Absolutely

Comment: If that, if I have a large number of record. How is performance? Should I use aggregate or update

Comment: You should go with update query and if you can update the mongodb version then you can use aggregation operator with the update query

Comment: Can you give me a link about aggregation operator with the update query? Thanks

Comment: @VũAnhDũng Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field